# How Do I Display First Name From Registration Form on Profile Page using UseContext API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-context

I am Creating A login/ Registration Form in React that displays the person username in the profile page once they login.The profile page displays fine, except for the name of the user who logged in which doesent appear on the profile page. I tried using the UseContext API but it doesent seem to display and when I try to log it to console it gives me an empty value.

My Register Code

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { RegisterContext } from '../Contexts/RegisterContext';
import './register.css'
function Register() {
   
    const [lnameReg,setLnameReg]=useState('');
    const [org,setOrg]=useState('');
    const [emailReg,setEmailReg]=useState('');
    const [passwordReg,setpasswordReg]=useState('');
   const {fnameReg,setFnameReg}=useContext(RegisterContext)
  
    const register=()=>{
        axios.post('http://localhost:4060/users/new_user',{
          
          firstname:fnameReg,
          lastname:lnameReg,
          organization:org,
          email:emailReg,
          password:passwordReg,
      
        }).then((response)=>{console.log(response)})
       }
 
 
    return (
        <div className='registration'>
        <h2>Register New User</h2>
       
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text"
          onChange={(e)=>{
            setFnameReg(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text"
          onChange={(e)=>{
            setLnameReg(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
         <label>Organization:</label>
        <input type="text"
          onChange={(e)=>{
            setOrg(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text"
          onChange={(e)=>{
            setEmailReg(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="text"
         onChange={(e)=>{
          setpasswordReg(e.target.value);
        }}
        />
        <button onClick={register}>Register</button>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Register
```

My Login Code

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import {  useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import axios from 'axios';
import { fetchToken, setToken } from "./Auth";
import './login.css'
import { RegisterContext } from '../Contexts/RegisterContext';
function Login() {
  
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const {usernamelog,setUsernamelog}=useContext(RegisterContext)
    const [passwordlog,setPasswordlog]=useState('');
    
    const [loginStatus,setLoginStatus]=useState('')
   
    var loginFormData = new FormData();
    loginFormData.append('username', usernamelog);
    loginFormData.append('password', passwordlog);
   
    const Login=()=>{
      
        axios(    
        {
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://localhost:4060/login',
          data: loginFormData,
          headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        })
        
        
        .then((response)=>{

          console.log(response.data, "response.data.token");
          if (response.data) {
            setToken(response.data);
            navigate("/profile");
          }
        })
        .catch((response)=>{
          console.log(response);
        })

       }
  
    return (
    <div className='Login'>
          <h2>Login</h2>
          <input type= "text" placeholder="Email"
           onChange={(e)=>{
            setUsernamelog(e.target.value);
          }}
          
          
          />
       
          <input type= "password" placeholder="password"
           onChange={(e)=>{
            setPasswordlog(e.target.value);
          }}
          />
          <button onClick={Login}>Login</button>
          <h3>{loginStatus}</h3>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

My Profile Code

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import Login from "./login";
import './profile.css'
import register from "./register";
import { RegisterContext } from "../Contexts/RegisterContext";
import { useContext } from "react";
export default function Profile() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const {fnameReg}=useContext(RegisterContext)
 
  const signOut = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem(<Login> usernamelog</Login>);
    navigate("/login");
  };
  console.log(fnameReg);
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20, minHeight: 700 }}>
        <h1>Profile page</h1>
         <h2>{fnameReg}</h2> 
        <p>Hello there, welcome to your profile page</p>

        <button onClick={signOut}>sign out</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

My App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {  useState } from 'react';
import * as yup from "yup";
import {userSchema} from './Validations/UserValid'
import { RequireToken } from "./components/Auth";
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home'; 
import Login from './components/login';
import Register from './components/register';
import Profile from './components/Profile';
import Survey from './components/Survey';

import { RegisterContext } from './Contexts/RegisterContext';

import React from 'react';
function App() {
  const [fnameReg,setFnameReg]=useState('');
  const [usernamelog,setUsernamelog]=useState('');
  

  const createUser= async (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    let formData ={
    firstname: event.target[0]?.value,
    lastname: event.target[1]?.value,
    organization: event.target[2]?.value,
    email: event.target[3]?.value,
    password: event.target[4]?.value,
    };
    const isValid= await userSchema.isValid(formData);
    console.log(isValid);

  };

 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RegisterContext.Provider value={{fnameReg,setFnameReg,usernamelog,setUsernamelog}} >
        <h1>Our Future Reads</h1>
          
        <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path ="/" element={<Home />}/>
          <Route path ="/survey" element={<Survey />}/>
          <Route path ="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
          
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route
  path="/profile"
  element={
    <RequireToken>
      <Profile />
    </RequireToken>
    
  }

/>
     
        </Routes>
        
      </Router>
          
          
      </RegisterContext.Provider>    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any Help Would be greatly appreciated and If you need any more information, feel free to ask and I will update the original Post. Thank You!

Comment: What you are trying to do is the wrong approach. You can't use the state of the registration form because there is likely page full page loads in between (like when they log out and back in again), which will totally clear down state. Also, what if the user just refreshes the page? Its all gone. The idea of using context for the user info is ok, but it should (and must) be populated from a call to the server to get those details.

Comment: How Would I go about doing that?

Comment: That depends entirely on your server implementation, and could well warrant an entirely new question. You already make calls to `http://localhost:4060/users/new_user` so you will need a new endpoint (unless one already exists...) like `/users/current_user` which returns that info based on the authenticated user. Once you had that, youd fetch it and provide the result down the context.

Comment: @adsy I have ```/users/{id}``` but im not sure how to use that. When The user registers they are given an Id but Idk how to get that id either.

Comment: It is quite likely to be in the response of the registration request, so you could try to parse it out of there. However, you still need to know it for users who hard refresh and are yet to go through registration. This depends on your auth mechanism -- is it cookie based or JWT/token?

Comment: @adsy It is Token Based

Comment: If so its likely the ID is in the token (probably in local storage). So you can just parse the token there and extract it. This is the usual approach to it. If its JWT you can just get a JWT parsing lib.

Comment: If the ID is not in there, you would need a new endpoint such as `/users/me` which uses the token server side to get the user and return the data for the *current* user.